# Storing more than one data in the array variable

Tags: php, mysql, session

I need some help with storing the data in the arrays. I have got a problem with the arrays variable `$_SESSION`, because it will only allow me to store one data at a time which it have overwritten the data.

When I try this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mydbusername', 'mydbpassword', 'mydbname');
$campaign_db = "SELECT campaign_name FROM campaign WHERE username = 'myusername'";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $campaign_db))
{
    // Set parameters
    $param_username = $_SESSION['username'];

    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
    {
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM))
        {
            foreach ($rows as $campaign)
            {
                $_SESSION['campaign'] = $campaign;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($_SESSION);
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}
```

I will only get this:

```
Array
(
    [campaign] => facebook
)
```

It should be:

```
Array 
( 
    [campaign] => somename [campaign] => youtube [campaign] => google [campaign] => linkedlin [campaign] => bing [campaign] => facebook 
)
```

I have tried this:

```
$_SESSION['campaign'][] = $campaign;
```

It give me an error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings. Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown.

Can you please show me an example how I can insert and store more than 1 data in the array for the variable `$_SESSION`?

**EDIT: When I try this:**

```
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    $_SESSION['campaign'] = array($rows);
)
```

And I have also try this:

```
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    foreach ($rows as $campaign)
    {
        $_SESSION['campaign'] = array($campaign);
    }
)
```

It still give me this:

```
 [campaign] => Array
    (
        [0] => facebook
    )
```

Comment: your "It should be:" is not a valid array, keys must be unique

Comment: @IdontDownVote what i should use then?

Comment: numeric keys like like nick shows below

Comment: I have tried it but it give me this `[0] => facebook` when i tried this `$_SESSION['campaign'] = array($campaign);`

Comment: This code is open to sql injection. Using `prepare()` doesn't constitute as a "prepared statement" per se; you should use one.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you for your advice. I am happy to change my code to prevent any sql injection attack. Can you please post the code that I should use to store the data in the array for the variable `$_SESSION`?

Comment: @IdontDownVote Please see the update code I have tried both different ways but no success :(

Comment: It's hard to say as to how the session array(s) was/were created. Why are you wanting to use a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Because I am working on a login page to fetch the data from the database. Why do you want to know?

Comment: im confused but you could try: `while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    $_SESSION['campaign'][] = $rows['campaign_name'];
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have initialised `$_SESSION['campaign']` to a string somewhere in your code. Wherever you did that you need to change it to

```
$_SESSION['campaign'] = array('string value')
```

or if it's an empty string then just use `array()` and then you will be able to use

```
$_SESSION['campaign'][] = $campaign;
```

in your loop.

Comment: thank you for this, but when I try this in the loop: `$_SESSION['campaign'] = array($campaign);`, it give me this `[0] => facebook`. Any idea?

Comment: @RobertJones you need to use `$_SESSION['campaign'] = array();` outside the loop, then inside the loop you would use `$_SESSION['campaign'][] = $campaign;`

Comment: Oh I didn't realised that I need to use `$_SESSION['campaign'] = array();` outside the loop so when I insert the `$_SESSION['campaign'][] = $campaign;` inside the loop, it works great. Thank you very much for your help so problem are now resolved.